# Sara has lived in Paris

Tags: meaning, tenses, present-perfect, semantics

I don't understand. What does the sentence mean? Is she still living in Paris or has she moved out?

Comment: what does your research reveal if you please?

Comment: Without further information, _Sara has lived in Paris_ means she lived there for some time in the past but does not live there now. However, if you add _for 20 years_, the presupposition is that she does still live in Paris, and did so for the last 20 years. If you wanted to refer to any other 20 years in the past, you'd have to say _She lived in Paris for 20 years_, which presupposes she left, and that the 20 years mentioned are not the last 20 years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New way of understanding the present perfect tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279143/new-way-of-understanding-the-present-perfect-tense)

Comment: also related: [“I have received” vs. “I received”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65864/i-have-received-vs-i-received) and [When to use “has lived” vs. “lived” vs. “had lived”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19471/when-to-use-has-lived-vs-lived-vs-had-lived)

Comment: and [Between Present Perfect and Simple Past, which tense indicates a finished action?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/between-present-perfect-and-simple-past-which-tense-indicates-a-finished-action) and [Present perfect for past action with present effect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/present-perfect-for-past-action-with-present-effect)

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of this sentence (present perfect) suggests that she no longer lives there.

"Sara has lived in Paris" - at some point in time (we don't know for how long, or when it was) Sara lived in Paris. The experience of living in Paris has now finished, thus the sentence describes a past experience, rather than a present reality which would be described via the present simple ("Sara lives in Paris").